# Constructor undefined

Tags: java, constructor

the question for my assignment is:

Create a java file named Book.java that will hold information describing a Book. The information required is:

a) Author

b) Title

c) Publisher

d) Year of Publication

e) Number of Pages

Use appropriate data types for each piece of information.
The class will need a constructor, getter and setter methods for each variable, and a toString method that prints a description of the Book.

I Keep getting an error saying the Constructor book is not defined.
any ideas on how to fix this?

```
    class Book {

      String author;
      String title;
      String publisher;
      int year;
      int pages;
    /** The following methods are the Getters for 
      * Author
      * title 
      * number of pages
      * year of publication 
    */
    public String getTitle() 
    {
      return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor()
    {
      return author;
    }

    public int getPages()
    {
      return pages;

    }
    public int getYear() 
    {
      return year;
    }

    //:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    /**the following Methods are Setters for 
      * Author 
      * title 
      * numer of pages 
      * year of publication
    */
    public void setTitle(String title)
     {
      this.title = title;

     }
    public void setAuthor(String author)
    {
      this.author = author;
    }

    public void setPages(int pages)
    {
      this.pages= pages;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) 
    { 
      this.year=year;

    }
    /*::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
     * Constructors for:
     * Author 
     * Title 
     * Pages 
     * Year 
     * prama@ a, t, p, y
     * */
    public Book (String a, String t, int p, int y) {
      author=a; 
      title=t; 
      pages =p; 
      year = y; 


    }
    public String toString (String a, String t, int p, int y){
        String b = title + "\nAuthor: " + author + "\nNumber of Pages: " +          pages+"/nYear of publication"
          +year;
        return b;
    }

    public void main (String  [] args) {

     Book b = new Book ("The Gunslinger", "Stephen King", "224", "1982") ;//error here
        System.out.println (b);

    }
}
```

Comment: ur constructor should take 5 parameters.it seems u forget about publisher ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"224"` is a `String`. The constructor expects `int` arguments for the third and fourth parameter:

```
Book b = new Book ("The Gunslinger", "Stephen King", 224, 1982);
```

In addition, the overriden `Object#toString()` method must not have any parameters:

```
public String toString () {
    String b = title + "\nAuthor: " + author + "\nNumber of Pages: " +          pages+"/nYear of publication"
      +year;
    return b;
}
```

Comment: ok nevermind I fixed that, and now it seems to be running but the output is:    Book@6153e9
How do I fix that?

Comment: @CoriSparks Printing the `Book` is supposed to be handled by overriding the `Object.toString()` method -- with no parameters, which is not the case in your code.

Comment: I am not following. what can I do to fix it?

Comment: @CoriSparks See my edited answer. The method `toString()` must not have any parameters. Otherwise, it would not override the `Object#toString()` that is invoked when printing the object.

Answer (score 2):

Call this

```
Book b = new Book ("The Gunslinger", "Stephen King", "224", "1982") ;
```

like

```
Book b = new Book ("The Gunslinger", "Stephen King",224,1982) ;
```

There is constructor:

```
Book(String,String,int,int)
```

not

```
Book(String,String,String,String)
```